# How to show form results even when pressing the back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form which a user selects a location. It has `remote: true` on it and its setup so i can bring results back in an ajax way.

form

```
<%= form_for :location, url: get_inventory_path, remote: true do |f| %>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <%= f.select :location_id, options_for_select(@locations.collect { |l|
                [l.station + ', ' + l.venue + ', ' + l.area + ', ' + l.city + ', ' + l.country, l.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'location_select', class: "browser-default" } %>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action center-align">
        <%= f.submit "Go", class: "btn blue", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." } %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

The thing is, on the results i have some buttons to edit those results, which takes the user to another page, but on pressing the back button the form results are not there.

How can i show those results, or remember them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you load the ajax data based on the value of a select box. And the problem is, when you redirect from this page to some other page, you lose your ajax data, when coming back.

One way to fix that can be, whenever the value in select box changes, save the location in session through the same ajax request which loads the data and when coming back to this page, check if a location is set in session and show the data for that location.

Comment: Hello there thank you for your answer, do you have a code snippet so i can get an idea of what you are talking about, as i have not experience with getting location of ajax request?

Comment: When a user clicks on the submit button in your form, a request will be sent to `get_inventory_path` with `location_id` in params. So, in your controller action, you can do `session[:location_id] = params[:location][:location_id]`.

Comment: And when visiting this page with the form, you can set `@location_id = session[:location_id]` in its controller action. Then in view, you can show the inventory data for this location which you otherwise fetch from `get_inventory_path`.

Comment: ok all good so far, but how do i trigger the form to show the inventory based on @location_id by just going to the page and not clicking the submit button?

Comment: you know what? i realised what you were talking about and thank you i solved it! :)

Comment: Great. Glad to help.